# If $f$ is continuous and $g\in C_c(X)$, then $fg\in C_c(X)$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff space. If $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $g\in C_c(X)$, is it true that $fg\in C_c(X)$? While I was doing a technical proof, I want to justify a certain step, which is why I ask this one. Clearly, $fg$ is continuous on $X$, but I do not know if $\operatorname{supp}fg$ is compact. It is a subset of $\operatorname{supp}g$ that is compact. Thanks for your time

Comment: $supp (fg) \subseteq supp (g)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I know, but what/why does it make compact?

Comment: Support is always closed by definition. Any closed subset of  a compact set is compact.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Uf. That part of $\operatorname{supp}$ being closed was totally forgotten. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\operatorname{supp}{fg} \subseteq \operatorname{supp}(g)$ because $g(x)=0$ implies $(fg)(x) =0$ essentially. It can be strictly smaller, as $f$ can be $0$ when $g$ is not etc. As $\operatorname{supp}(h)$ is defined as a closed set (in analysis and topology, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)), e.g.), usually as $\overline{X\setminus h^{-1}[\{0\}]}$ and $\operatorname{supp}(g)$ is compact and $\operatorname{supp}(fg)$ is a closed subspace of it, it is also compact (in any space).